# Are there some known methods to improve Apple Push Notifications store-and-forward function to store more than one notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm currently struggle with annoying store-and-forward function limitation of `APNS`. Here is a quote from the Apple docs:

```
If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline,
the notification is stored for a limited period of time, 
and delivered to the device when it becomes available. Only ONE recent 
notification for a particular application is stored. If multiple notifications
are sent while the device is offline, each new notification causes the prior 
notification to be DISCARDED.
```

I specifically make ALL CAPS for the keywords of my problem. In Google Cloud Messaging notifications service their store and forward function have much more capabilities:`There is a limit on how many messages can be stored without collapsing. That limit is currently 100. If the limit is reached, all stored messages are discarded.` - so Google service can store up to 100 push messages for a max time of 28 days. And in addition to this they have also coalescing (collapsible) notifications but for 4 different collapsible messages. And in APNS all we have is - `one recent 
    notification for a particular application is stored` - it is quite a limited behaviour for my app (I need to store at least four different push notifications while the device is offline at one given moment of time).

So I'm interested are there some ways I can improve store and forward capability of APNS?? Can I in some way make APNS to store more push notifications for a specific device?Or at least store several coalescing notifications as in Google collapsible messages? Some third party solutions or whatever? May be I missed something in APNS docs? I know we can [orchestrate](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/ios-push-notifications) apple push notification on google platform - but I think it is not a solution because of its unjustified complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found yourself in Apple's APNS docs, there is no way to store more than one notification per application for a single device. If you want to compare it to GCM, APNS server acts as if all notifications have the same collapse key.

No third party solutions can work around that, since Apple doesn't return an acknowledgment of delivery to the sender of the notification, so the server (whether it's implemented by you or by some third party provider) has no way of knowing which messages to store and resend (assuming that all the messages are valid and were not rejected by APNS server).

Apple Push Notifications are not intended to deliver important data. Their purpose is to notify the user of the app that new data is available at the server, which allows the app to load that data if the user chooses to open the app. That's the reason why they don't store more than one message per app for the same device.